# Show that for a given $s$ there are a finite number of Fibonacci number of form $n^2+s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

It is well known that the last Fibonacci number $F_k$ such that $\exists \ n \in \Bbb{N} : F_k = n^2$ is $144$.  Thus there are only $4$ perfect squares among the Fibonacci sequence (assuming  you count $F_0 = 0$ and count the duplicated $F_1 = F_2 = 1$).

The equation 
$$F_k = n^2 + 4
$$
also has a few solutions ($F_5 = 1^2 + 4, F_6 = 2^2 +4, f_7 = 3^2+4$) and appears to have no other solutions (although my proof of that might well have some holes).

**Pretty Hard Question**

Prove that 
$$F_k = n^2 + 1
$$
and 
$$F_k = n^2 -1
$$
each have only a finite number of solutions for $k,n \in \Bbb{N}$.

**Challenging Question**

Are there any values of $s$ such that

$$F_k = n^2 +s
$$
has no solutions for $k,n \in \Bbb{N}$?

**Very Challenging Question:**

Prove that for any $s \in \Bbb{Z}$ 
$$F_k = n^2 + s
$$
has only a finite number of solutions for $k,n \in \Bbb{N}$.

(Or find a counterexample $s$.)

Comment: Even the result you said it's "well known" is not easy to prove

Comment: Yes, it is half as hard as my "pretty hard question." BUt you can find an understandable proof on the web.

Comment: This website is not really a place to share hard problem but to help others in mathematics, If you're interested I have an old question here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1149504/204937

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at the $n^2$ proof, and see whether you can modify it to solve one/some of the other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pretty hard question is completely resolved in [this](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~maseap/papers/fnpm.pdf) paper. The authors show that the only perfect *powers* (not only perfect squares!) which are at distance $1$ from a Fibonacci number are $0,1,2,3,5,8$.

Answer (score 2):

**Pretty Hard Question: Partial Answer**

$For\quad the\quad case\quad when\quad F_{ n }=m^{ 2 }+1,\quad F_{ n }-1=m^{ 2 }$

I.  $n=4k\quad F_{4k}-1=F_{2k+1}L_{2k-1}$.

Note $L_{2k-1}=F_{2k+1}-F_{2k-3}$ where $gcd(F_{2k+1},F_{2k-3})=1$
Therefore, $L_{2k-1} and F_{2k+1}$ are relatively prime, and both must be squares. However, $L_{n}$ and $F_{n}$ both have only a finite number of solutions when they are square. Our proof is done.

II. $n=4k+1\quad F_{4k+1}-1=F_{2k}L_{2k+1}$.

Note $L_{2k+1}=F_{2k}+F_{2k+2}$ where $gcd(F_{2k+2},F_{2k})=1$. 
Therefore, $L_{2k+1} and F_{2k}$ are relatively prime, and both must be squares. However, $L_{n}$ and $F_{n}$ both have only a finite number of solutions when they are square. Our proof is done.

While I haven't been able to try the rest, I think they would follow a similar pattern.

Formula Used Presented in

[Fibonacci[n]-1 is always composite for n>6. why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16877/fibonaccin-1-is-always-composite-for-n6-why?lq=1)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number